# How to use a companion fare if the total fare cost is more than the companion fare limit

Tags: credit-card, airline, frequent-flier-miles

I am looking at the [Alaska Airlines Master Card](http://rewardscanada.ca/mbna.html)

And I see:

```
An annual coach Companion Fare every year from $118 (USD)($99 base fare, plus taxes and fees from $19)
```

Now let us say I purchase a full fare ticket or I purchase a ticket with accumulated miles on Alaska Air. For my companion, if the ticket cost is 500$ (RT), then can I use the 99 $ towards that 500 and pay the balance 401$ in cash?

Or this is useful only if the total fare is 99$ or less?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must buy both tickets in 1 transaction and the purchased ticket cannot be purchased with miles.

You'll pay full price (technically a "paid published coach airfare") for the first ticket and enter in your discount code for the companion fare which will ring up as $99 + fees ($118 in your example).

If the regular price is $500, you'll book 2 tickets for $618 (one fare at $500 and companion fare at $118).

> Companion Fare Discount Code Q & A
>
> What is the Companion Fare Discount Code that comes with my credit
>   card?
>
> The Companion Fare Discount Code is offered to holders of the
>   Alaska Airlines Visa Signature® Card, The Platinum Plus® MasterCard®
>   and the Visa® Business Card. This Discount Code entitles the
>   cardholder to purchase one round-trip coach companion fare on Alaska
>   Airlines from $121 (USD) ($99 base fare plus applicable taxes and fees
>   from $22 depending on your Alaska Airlines flight itinerary) when
>   **traveling with another passenger on a paid published coach airfare on
>   the same itinerary, booked at the same time. Mileage cannot be used as
>   a form of payment**, however mileage credit accrual is allowed for both
>   travelers. Travelers are responsible for all applicable taxes, fees,
>   surcharges and applicable checked baggage fees. The Companion Fare
>   Discount Code is not valid with award travel, and cannot be combined
>   with other discounts.

Source: [Alaska Air Companion Fair Q&A](http://www.alaskaair.com/content/mileage-plan/frequently-asked-questions/faq-companion-discount-code.aspx)